# How to use jenkins+sonarqube+gitea to statically check the remote repository when the remote repository submits a merge request

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube, gitea

I want to pull the remote repository and do static checking when the remote repository submits a merge request.

I have integrated Jenkins with Sonarqube, and want to implement static inspection of the remote repository through a pipeline.
I tried to modify the URL in the jenkinsfile, but I wanted to be able to adapt more automatically from different remote repositories instead of manually changing the URL every time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQZUe.png)
Is there any good way to enable Jenkins to pull the remote repository when the remote repository submits a merge request?

Comment: Please don't add code as image; always use formatted text. Others may want to search for the text or copy and paste.